# Спорити - питоме чи запозичене слово?

Tags: значення-слів, дієслова, росіянізм

В рекламі [ФАВОРИТ СПОРТ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRWO5rW0Y4s) запитують - "Споримо?"
Мені здавалося "споримо" - російське слово, проте в СУМ-11 присутнє визначення

> ***[СПОРИТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/sporyty)*** **1.** *розм.* Те саме, що сперечатися. **2.** *перен.* Змагатися, не поступатися у чому-небудь.

У визначені присутня позначка *розм.*, тобто слово краще не вживати в діловому письмі. 
Цікавить чи не запозичене "спорити/споримо" з російської?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Етимологічний словник](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) у словниковій статті із словом **спорити** відсилає нас до **перти 3**:
[image]
    [image]

Отже, воно питоме (походить ще з праслов'янського *pertі, *pьrǫ і присутнє в багатьох інших слов'янських мовах)

Comment: будь ласка, зробіть знятки екрану так, щоб було бачити, що пише по боках.

Comment: Врахувала зауваження